# Fill a 2D matrix with given value in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have an array like:

```
[[0,2,_9492],[2,_9510,_9516],[_9528,_9534,_9540]]
```

i want to fill all unbound(i.e. have random values) element to `-1`

Needed result

```
[[0,2,-1],[2,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1]]
```

what i tried

```
fillArray([H|T],[H1|T1]):-fillRow(H,H1),fillArray(T,T1).
fillRow([H|_], _):-nonvar(H),fail.
fillRow([0|_], _).
fillRow([H|T],[-1|B]):-fillRow(T,B).
```

What i got is `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problem of your code is that you need also the base case for the predicates (the case needed to terminate the recursion).
You can fix it like this:

```
fillArray([],[]).
fillArray([H|T],[H1|T1]):-
    fillRow(H,H1),
    fillArray(T,T1).

fillRow([],[]).
fillRow([H|T],[H|T1]):- 
    nonvar(H),
    fillRow(T,T1).
fillRow([H|T],[-1|T1]):- 
    var(H),
    fillRow(T,T1).

?- L = [[0, 2, -1], [2, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]
false
```

You can add some cuts to remove the choice points. This is a basic solution. You can use also more advanced predicates like `maplist/3`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using lambda expression in SWI-Prolog

An advanced solution in SWI-Prolog is:

```
set_unbound(Value, Matrix) :-
    Lambda = {Value} / [X]>>(var(X) -> X=Value ; true),
    maplist(maplist(Lambda), Matrix).
```

Examples:

```
?- M = [[0,2,_],[2,_,_],[_,_,_]], set_unbound(-1, M).
Ma = [[0, 2, -1], [2, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]].

?- M = [[0,_],[_,2]], set_unbound(9, M).
M = [[0, 9], [9, 2]].

?- M = [[1,_],[_,3]], set_unbound(V, M).
M = [[1, V], [V, 3]].
```